# Yahoo OAuth authorization issue when implementing the yahoo search in my site using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api

I tried to use the `OAuth` for yahoo search. I am new to this concept.

I registered in yahoo and got consumer and secret key.

I implemented it using `JavaScript`, when I test my code (test.js) using `node.js`(i installed ***npm install oauth –g***) i got the following `error` instead of XML.

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

**TEST.JS**

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;
var key = 'dj0yJmk9cU5GT2p5T0VRc3R2JmQ9WVdrOVZHeFZaR1YwTjJFbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1lYg--';
var secret = 'e766c8cbd1c7b31612b1787e1f39b7b27a88433d';
var webSearchUrl = 'https://ysp.yahooapis.com/ysp/web';
var finalUrl = webSearchUrl + '?q=iphone';
var oa = new OAuth(webSearchUrl, webSearchUrl, key, secret, "1.0", null, "HMAC-SHA1", null, {"Accept-Language": null, "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0", "Cookie" : ""});
oa.setClientOptions({ requestTokenHttpMethod: 'GET' });
oa.get(finalUrl, '','', function (error, data, resp) {
    if (error || resp.statusCode !== 200) { // if there is a error, exit with error message
        return console.log(error);
    } 
    // otherwise, echo incoming data
    console.log(data);
});
```

[image]

Please help me in this to get the `XML` data for processing. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update to the Question**

After trying the implementation in the link given by michaelchum in test.js I go the following error PFA SS and test2.js code.

**Test2.js**

```
var YaBoss = require('yaboss');
var YaBossClient = new YaBoss('someCustomerKey', 'someCustomerSecret');

YaBossClient.search('web','yahoo', {count: 10}, function(err,dataFound,response){
    console.log("Data :*****");
    console.log(dataFound);
    console.log("Error :*****");
    console.log(err);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Yahoo Search BOSS API requires **OAuth1.0A**, you've selected OAuth1.0 in your OAuth library call.

There is actually a [Yahoo Search API npm package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/yaboss), you should take a look, it will make the implementation much easier.

Try this:

Make a new folder and a new file `app.js`

```
var YaBoss = require('yaboss');

var key = 'dj0yJmk9cU5GT2p5T0VRc3R2JmQ9WVdrOVZHeFZaR1YwTjJFbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1lYg--';
var secret = 'e766c8cbd1c7b31612b1787e1f39b7b27a88433d';

var YaBossClient = new YaBoss(key, secret);

YaBossClient.search('web','yahoo', {count: 10}, function(err,dataFound,response){
    console.log("Data :*****");
    console.log(dataFound);
    console.log("Error :*****");
    console.log(err);
});
```

In the folder do `npm install yaboss` and then `node app.js`

Comment: "var YaBoss = require('yaboss');
    var YaBossClient = new YaBoss('someCustomerKey', 'someCustomerSecret');"..... Where Can i place my websearch url "var webSearchUrl = 'https://ysp.yahooapis.com/ysp/web';"

Comment: :Thanks a lot for the help. After trying the implementation in the url you have given. I got the same result. PFA test2.js and the result in the question(I updated it)

Comment: Make sure your packages are up-to-date, and your consumer key and secret are right.Just use `npm install` don't use `-g`. Sorry I can't test the package for you, since I'm not subscribed to the BOSS API. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried you're key and secret and it works for me! Make sure you have a clean install of node. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is now working for me. I was scratching my head for the past three days.

Comment: Thanks again.How to find the url which i am connecting to get data?. because my firewall in workstation is blocking that url. I am able to get the response from my PC, but firewall is blocking in my workstation, to remove it from firewall i need the url.

Comment: Did you try unblocking yahooapis.com ?

Comment: I want to do ysp to the url "var webSearchUrl = 'https://ysp.yahooapis.com/ysp/web';
var finalUrl = webSearchUrl + '?q=iphone&format=xml';"....but i am getting the error "non ysp request from ysp customer"

Comment: when i try from my browser i got the "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. ". Is there any way to make the XML response from cross domain working for this yahoo ouath?